# Android eclipse button and spinner(s)

Tags: android

i want to have a validation for my spinners(using a button), if the user of my app doesn't select an item or the user selected the same value(the spinner have a value "Please select something" and other values) for example in array list of spinner items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="condition_prompt">the condition of the car</string>

    <string-array name="condition_arrays">
        <item>-Please select something-</item> <!-- Hint --> 
        <item>New</item>
        <item>Used</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

and this validation will triggered whenever the user hit(click) the button.I'm using a button to validate these spinner cause this button will also validate the value of my edittext, my app have some edittexts and spinners and then when all filled then the button will start new activity.For the edittext i already did the validation and works perfectly(it will toast a text "please fill the edittext").Now what i need is the validation for my spinners. I did the code for it but it has an error

The code

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View seletedItem, int pos, long id)
       {
          String item1 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
       }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {

        }
});

spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItem, int pos, long id)
        {
           String item2 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {

        }
    });
spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItem, int pos, long id)
        {
           String item3 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {

        }
    });
buttonvalidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String ethint2 = ethint1.getText().toString();
                String etpersen3 =etpersen2.getText().toString();

                 if(ethint2.trim().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "pls fill the price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                else if(etpersen3.trim().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "pls fill the percentage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;

                }
                   /*i want to add more else if whenen button clicked it will also remind the user if the user doesn't select an item from the spinner or the user will select the "please select something" again with a toast text saying"please pick lol or please pick blaalalal(just example)" */          
            }
        });
```

if i add else if on `public void onClick` like  `else if(item1.equals("Please select something")){ do the toast text here }` there will be an error saying item1 cannot be resolved in variables. I'm looking for a better implementation or correction of my code.Thanks in advance

trying to change the code, log cat error:

```
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg/com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.Mastercode}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.Mastercode.onCreate(Mastercode.java:84)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-18 16:26:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  ... 11 more
```

The Working code:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View seletedItem, int pos, long id)
           {
              String item1 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
           }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }
    });

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItem, int pos, long id)
            {
               String item2 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }
        });
    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View selectedItem, int pos, long id)
            {
               String item3 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }
        });
 public void buttonvalidator(View v){
                    String ethint2 = ethint1.getText().toString();
                    String etpersen3 =etpersen2.getText().toString();                                                           
                        if(ethint2.trim().equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please fill the price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else if(etpersen3.trim().equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please fill the percentage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;

                        }
                        else if(item1.toString().equals("-Please select the car condition-")){
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please select the condition of the car", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else if(item2.toString().equals("-Please select the kind of your car insurance-")){
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please select the kind of your car insurance", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else if(item3.toString().equals("-Please select the zone-")){
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please select the zone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                }
```

the button code can also written like this

```
public void buttonvalidator(View v){
                    String ethint2 = ethint1.getText().toString();
                    String etpersen3 =etpersen2.getText().toString();                                                           
                        if(ethint2.trim().equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please fill the price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        else if(etpersen3.trim().equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please fill the percentage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;   
                        }
                        else if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("-Please select something-")){
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please select something from spinner1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                            }
                         else if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("-Please select something-")){
                            Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please select something from spinner2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                            }
                         else if(spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("-Please select something-")){Toast.makeText(Mastercode.this, "Please select something from spinner3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                            }
                }
```

the buttonvalidator is from the layout.xml  on button

```
<button 
android:OnClick="buttonvalidator"/>
```

Comment: why your question is always down-voted?

Comment: i have no idea, maybe someone been down-voting people around or the community(there is a question(post) about the community down-voting posts)

Comment: this url http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286149/why-community%E2%99%A6-downvoting-questions-answers?cb=1   or this one    http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286207/down-vote-favorite-appearing-in-many-posts?cb=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `item1,item2,item3` at class level instead of in scope of method to access in whole class.

Suggestion is use `spinner1.getSelectedItem()` inside `onClick` method of Button to get selected values from Spinner:

```
if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(
                               "Please select something")){
   // do the toast text here
}else if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(
                                  "Please select something")){
   // do the toast text here
}
.....
```

Comment: the .trim() is red underlined ,it gives an error saying"The method trim() is undefined for the type Object" .When i deleted trim() there is no error but the app will crash .I'll give the log cat

Comment: editted the editted:i missunderstood your comment then made this one   if(item3.toString().equals("-Please select something-")).   its working both the code written like this one if(spikon.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("-Please select something-"))    or like this      if(item3.toString().equals("-Please select something-"))  .thank you its now working perfectly

Comment: wait, which one you prefer to use?

Comment: @georgesamuel: both is fine but if `trim()` then it will remove space if spinner selected item contain

Comment: what do you mean?i'm bit confused

Comment: @georgesamuel: using `if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()`  is good because no need to use extra variables